# Generate Mnemonic Phrase from window.crpyto.subtle.generateKey

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum, webcrypto-api, end-to-end-encryption

I am developing and web based end to end encrypted chat website. For that I am generating private keys using the window.crypto.subtle.generateKey function provided in the web crypto api.

I want the user to remember or store a mnemonic phrase like we use in ethereum wallets instead of an encryption key.

Is there a way to generate the mnemonic phrase from the private key that is generated by the window.crypto.subtle.generateKey function or is there any other way I should go to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there a way to generate the mnemonic phrase from the private key*

It's the other way around. A set of private keys can be determined from each mnemonic phrase - but you can't determine a mnemonic from a private key.

---

A widely-used standard is [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki). Even though it was first introduced as a Bitcoin Improvement Protocol, many Ethereum wallets use it too. You can find its JS implementation in [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39) for example.

*Note: You're looking for functions `mnemonicToSeed()` and `mnemonicToSeedSync()`. Even though it might seem at the first look that `entropyToMnemonic()` translates private key to the phrase, it's not true - the entropy numbers are just positions of the words in the wordlist, not the private key bytes.*

Comment: Ok so I'll use bip39.generateMnemonic() to generate the mnemonic and use one of the private keys generated by this mnemonic (using mnemonicToSeed()) to encrypt and decrypt the messages right?

Comment: Ok thanks, and how do I select one private key from the set of keys generated from that phrase?

Comment: The linked NPM package only returns the first key of the set. However, the standard defines multiple keys per phrase - so some other packages may be able to return more than one key.

Answer (score 3):

What you want, as you describe it, is to *encode* your private key into mnemonic words. Which you totally can, with the simplest example being: split up the key into chunks of n-bits, and match each chunk to a word list consisting of 2^n words.

Whether you actually want this for your overall purposes is a different question.

I'd also like to expand on Petr Hejda's answer, which at first confused me, but I now understand.

Petr is using the definition of "private key" in a different context than in the question. Petr is referring to "private keys" in terms of the bitcoin protocol, where the mnemonic is not used as an encoding for private keys, but to generate a seed which may then be used to generate any number of keys deterministically (BIP-0032), so that such generated keys can be re-generated when using the same seed, which in turn can be re-generated from the mnemonic. In this protocol, the mnemonic-to-seed is defined, but seed-to-mnemonic is not, because the protocol never does that. It only generates mnemonics from entropy, and then generate the seed from the mnemonic.

But in your case, you can simply feed it your "private key" (as you've defined it) as the "entropy" input in the `entropyToMnemonic()` function, and it will give you the *mnemonic encoding* of the "private key" that you wanted. You'll still have to decode it yourself though, as the BIP39 package doesn't have that functionality.